# Why is this Meta post closed as Primarily Opinion Based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

"[Why so many downvotes in one day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260190/why-so-many-downvote-in-one-day)" has been closed as "Primarily Opinion Based".

As someone who's not used to Meta Stack Overflow's decisions on opinion-based questions, what's the quick rundown for this question? I would probably have chosen another reason had I been confident enough to do so, so it'd be nice to know what criteria make this a close-as-opinion question.

Alternatively, is there a standard reference for how to vote that covers this?

Comment: Because the general body would have to speculate about why there were downvotes and offer their opinions based on that speculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [What's Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), the OP at least used the correct tag:

> [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion), for posts that may not have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature request, it is probably a discussion.

However, the question itself has *many* possible answers: it's asking why people downvoted, which is an unanswerable question.

Why do people steal?

Why do people lie?

Why do people ask bad questions on SO?

Asking people why other people did something is counterproductive, and the multitude of answers that follow will likely be not only terribly subjective, but also incorrect.

Comment: The analogies are hilarious. Have a bit of green.

Comment: people steal because they are anonymous or think they will stay so
putting votes public would solve half problem... still bad question would occour, on the process of filtering bad questions we are also downvoting the person.. it makes sense, but sometimes i would rater downvote the question, not the person

Comment: @neu-rah Making votes public would make things much worse; it would lead to an endless cycle of revenge downvoting.

Comment: yeah, assuming most of people are negative... you may have a point there

Answer (score 4):

The question-asker was asking why he got downvoted a Stack Overflow question he'd asked. Voting is completely anonymous on Stack Overflow and the voting reason is not made public; nobody could really tell *why* the question was downvoted. If he'd phrased the question in a constructive tone, the question may not have been closed.

Comment: That pretty much covers the reasons I was unsure about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because answers to the question are not likely to be based on facts or evidence, but rather blind speculation.

Yes, meta posts are generally much more subjective than, say, SO questions.  [But there are both good and bad types of subjective questions.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)  That question is Bad Subjective.