# Why are questions on Meta closed as "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, meta

I wanted to get some clarification today regarding the voting system, especially on Stack Overflow. I stumbled upon a lot of questions whose answers helped me understand the voting system better, but the questions themselves had a lot of down votes, or were closed as "primarily opinion based". I understand why this close reason exists in all Stack Exchange sites, but not Meta. I thought Meta was a place to discuss the way the other sites work, I think that is subject to opinion. Was I wrong?

So I wonder, why are questions on Meta closed as "opinion-based"?
And more specifically, what types of questions are you allowed to ask on Meta?

If Meta is not a place for me to show disappointment in the way the voting system works and state my *opinion* as to why I don't really like it, what would be an appropriate place to do so?

Comment: The answer here explains some cases why meta questions are closed as "opinion-based": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260259/why-is-this-meta-post-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: I'm with you there up until _If meta is not a place for me to show disappointment in the way the voting system works, and state my OPINION as to why I don't really like it_ that sounds like it would just be a rant and not seek any discussion.

Comment: @George not really, I exaggerated a bit. There are just some things I don't like about the voting system, I wanted to give some examples and what I think would be a better solution.

Comment: *votes to close this question as primarily opinion-based* </jk>

Comment: But honestly, this is probably answered by [Why is “primarily opinion-based” a valid close reason on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252237/4751173) and the one linked by Tom.

Comment: @IleanaProfeanu We'd be interested in your opinion as to why the voting system sucks if you'd read a significant number of questions and answers on meta which explain why it is the way it is and you had something **new** to say on the matter. We don't want yet another rehash of the same things again and again.

Comment: @Robert Longson I think it would be better for users with little reputation to be explained, or to have the possibility to request a mod to explain to them, why the question was downvoted, instead of discouraging them with 3 downvotes, as in the case of a friend of mine. also, I think one downvote would be enough. but I think I will ask a question about it. thank you all for your answers

Comment: @IleanaProfeanu a) That's not scalable. b) how is the mod supposed to read the mind of the 3 downvoters? c) The question is downvoted because it does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful.

Comment: @IleanaProfeanu 'it would be better for users with little reputation to be explained, or to have the possibility to request a mod to explain to them'.....' I think I will ask a question about it' - be very wary!    That issue has been discussed forever on meta.  There are dozens of Q&A threads on explaining, (or not), votes.  Unless you have something new to add, you can expect a bad reception.